# How to check if a variable is already declared (T-SQL)?

Tags: t-sql

When I write

```
DECLARE @x INT
```

Is there a way to check whether the variable @x has already been declared or not?

Answer (score 19):

No.
The declaration of variables in tsql does not follow the code path and use scope like perhaps other languages does.

This code shows that `@xx` exists but is unassigned even though the declaration was never executed.

```
if 1 = 0 
begin
  declare @xx int = 10
end
else
begin
  declare @yy int = 20
end

print coalesce(@xx, -100)
print coalesce(@yy, -200)
```

Result

```
-100
20
```

Comment: Just incase anyone else is also looking for a way to do this Try and catch blocks also wont work. if you want to check if a variable exists and then declare it if it doesn't.

Comment: Note also that a variable can never be uninitialised in T-SQL. if no explicit default value has been defined for the variable then implicit default value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

IF you try to access a variable that has not yet been defined, the T-SQL Script will give you an error telling you the variable isn't defined.

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@x".