# If SQL variable exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing some code that uses a significant quantity of dynamic SQL and as a result, there are some instances when a third party application may or may not have a SQL variable declared.

Is there a way to test if a variable has been declared.
Some psuedo code would be:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'@var' 
) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var AS varchar(max)
END
```

Also, is there a way to list all of the variables currently declared like a *local watch* window?

Comment: is the code with dynamic SQL a function or procedure? If so you can always assign a default value to all input variables in case they were not provided i.e.: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: While I'm not aware of any way to test whether a variable has already been declared, it seems to me that you would have two scenarios: if it doesn't exist, then no problems but if it does exist, then regardless of what you do, you're either going to have to use a different variable name or reassign the variable or your procedure will error. And in any of the situations in the second scenario, it seems to me that you'd be best trying to avoid that by just naming your variables with an unusual convention so as not to conflict with the third party (e.g. instead of @var, use @__var or something).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is already declared (T-SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541210/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-already-declared-t-sql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

T-SQL declares variables per-batch - they do not have any scoping. You need to ensure all the variables that are actually used are declared from the outside - by the time the batch runs, it's too late.

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, and what kind of constraints you can impose on the code fragments. One alternative would be to use something other than variables - for example, a common table variable that would be used for all the other "pseudo-variables". Something like this:

```
declare @parameters table
(
  Id varchar(20),
  Value sql_variant
);

-- This is the code generated by the 3rd party; update might be better than insert
insert into @parameters values ('MyVar', 42);

-- Using the variable - you get NULL or the actual value
declare @MyVar int;
select @MyVar = cast(Value as int) from @parameters where Id = 'MyVar';
```

All the variables are then declared by your part of the code (or not at all), and the 3rd party only has an option to change them from their defaults. Of course, this may be entirely useless for your use-case - it's not clear what kind of scenarios you're actually expecting to occur.

In general, slapping together pieces of T-SQL is tricky. Since there's no scoping, there's no way of preventing one fragment from destroying the whole batch. If you can afford any checks at all, they need to be on a different layer - and you may have to change the names of the variables in the fragments to avoid collisions. Another option might be to prohibit the 3rd party from declaring any variables at all, and instead requiring them to register a variable from your side - that would allow you to choose names that avoid conflicts.

Comment: Sorry for the tardy response. This is a perfect answer. The more time passes, the more I appreciate that answering "no" is a universal sign of wisdom. You managed to pretty well extrapolate what I was trying to accomplish and the alternative of leveraging a table as a means of manufacturing my own method for checking the existence is both eloquent and something I would not have thought of. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: If you say that T-SQL declares variables per batch, then I would say that variables have a batch-scope. In that case it would make sense to ask whether a variable is already declared in a batch right?

Comment: @JensWagemaker The thing is, T-SQL doesn't have batches - that comes from the outside, e.g. Management Studio separating the input by `GO` and executing each part as a separate command. As far as T-SQL is concerned, there is no scoping (or alternatively said, there's only one scope, which really means the same thing).